# Cascading parameter dropdowns without using a query SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to create cascading parameters via SSRS report params that are not query driven.  Is this possible or do I need to actually make a table containing the values I need?

[image]

So when the select Year I'd like the following:

- Interim To Date (value = -99)
- 1 Year Ago (value = -1)
- 2 Years Ago
- 3 Years Ago
- 4 Years Ago

When they select Month I'd like the following:

- Current Month (value  -int of today (so 09/13/2016 would be -13)
- 1 Month Ago (value = -30)
- 2 Months Ago (value = -60)
- 3 Months Ago
- 4 Months Ago
- 5 Months Ago
- 6 Months Ago
- 7 Months Ago
- 8 Months Ago
- 9 Months Ago
- 10 months Ago
- 11 Months Ago

I'm not looking for it all to be done just an example of how I might do one or two via expressions or if I really have to write a query to do this?

Comment: You know, you could store a dataset for a cascading parameter using embedded XML.  It's a relatively clean way to hold the information without needing to query back to the data source.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need a query but it will require multiple expressions. In the report parameter properties, create the expressions for the available values. From BID's help on the Today() function, there are the below example expressions.

> =Today()
>
> ="Tomorrow is " & DateAdd("d",1,Today())
>
> ="Tomorrow is " & DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,1,Today())

Therefore, the 1 Year ago would be `=DateAdd(DateInterval.Year,-1,Today())`. You would then need to do this for each value in the parameter list.

Personally, I get lazy and use a recursive query and use something like the below for a dataset. This will return 11 months, starting with this month and going back 10.

```
 WITH dates AS (SELECT        0 AS num
                           UNION ALL
                           SELECT        num - 1 AS Expr1
                           FROM            dates AS dates_2
                           WHERE        (num > - 10))
 SELECT        DateName(Month,DATEADD(Month, num, GETDATE())) As [MONTH]
 FROM            dates AS dates_1
```

This is a bit easier to maintain and you don't have to make an expression for each and every possible input for the user. Plus, DateName() and DateAdd() can be altered for different date parts and `(num > -10)` can be changed for how many items to return (going back).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create a table or query, you can still used an embedded XML dataset in your report for your second parameter's available values:

- Create an XML datasource.  Leave the connection string blank.
- Create a dataset with static embedded XML which contains a name, value, and value to filter different sets by.

Condensed for brevity:

```
<Query><XmlData><Root>
    <Item Name="1 Year Ago" Value="-1" SetName="Year" />
    <Item Name="2 Years Ago" Value="-2" SetName="Year" />
    <Item Name="3 Years Ago" Value="-3" SetName="Year" />
    <Item Name="1 Month Ago" Value="0" SetName="Month" />
    <Item Name="2 Months Ago" Value="-30" SetName="Month" />
    <Item Name="3 Months Ago" Value="-60" SetName="Month" />
</Root></XmlData></Query>
```

- Create a calculated field in the database to include the date adjustment for the "1 Month Ago" case:

`=IIF(Fields!Value.Value = 0, -1 * DatePart("d",Today()),Fields!Value.Value)`

- Set a filter on the data set filtering `[SetName]` to `[@DateType]`.
- Create a second cascading parameter that uses the XML dataset for its available values, using the calculated field.